# Stopping client thread when window is closed in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to stop the client thread when the client window is closed. Below is my code:

**Client.java**

```
public class Client extends Task {

private int portNumber = 8080;
private String hostName = "127.0.0.1";

public Client(){
    stage = new Stage();
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 250));
    stage.show();
}


@Override
protected Object call() throws Exception {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));) {
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Client is made by calling:

```
new Thread(new Client()).start();
```

This is called inside the `serverController`.

How do I stop/terminate the thread when the client window is closed? Thanks!

EDIT:

Managed to get it to work by following this example:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: You could use ```stage.setOnCloseRequest``` to add your own event handler on window close to stop the thread?

Comment: maybe setting the thread to daemon could also help

Comment: The `Task` you've shown doesn't actually do anything time consuming. It just creates a socket and then quits. Presumably there are some actual blocking calls somewhere in your real code. Can you [edit] the question to make it a bit more realistic? The problem is there's nothing to show you how to terminate in the code you've provided.

Comment: @James_D I managed to fix it by following this example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Best resource is probably just to read up on cancelable Tasks in the [Task Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).  For background information you may also wish to read up on a [cancelable task using an interrupt](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/).  Internally, the [cancel method of task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#cancel-boolean-) can generate interrupts if required.